# Change on send ok for javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

The code on_sent_ok is not working, how can i change it to a javascript.

```
on_sent_ok:"document.getElementById('formulariocontacto').style.display='none';"
on_sent_ok: "document.getElementById('formExtra').style.display='block';"
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing on_sent_ok with DOM Events.

Add this simple script in your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    document.getElementById('formulariocontacto').style.display='none'; 
    document.getElementById('formExtra').style.display='block';
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Contact Form gives me an error: Deprecated settings are used.

Comment: I read now in contact-form7 page... I correct my solution.. wait a min